# Null reference on SQLite query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I am trying to get data from my `sqlite` database. It gives me the error of `Attempt to invoke method on null reference.` I am trying to store the values using Hashmap.

Here's my code:

```
 class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mData;

        public MyAdapter() {
            mData = helper.getAllDataLV();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            return view;


        }
        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView tx_row;
        }
    }


public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllDataLV(){
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bets;",null);

if(cs != null && cs.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        HashMap<String, String> q = new HashMap<>();
        q.put("betnumber",  cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex("betnumber")));
        data.add(q);
    }while(cs.moveToNext());
}
System.out.println(data);

return data;
}
```

The error is in the `getAllDataLV()` function.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.example.zian.myDbAdapter.getAllDataLV()' on a null object reference

Comment: @forpas Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: It should. Do you initialize `myhelper` somewhere?

Comment: Kindly Edit question and add complete stacktrace of error

Comment: @forpas Yes, the getAllDataLV() is inside my MyDbHelper.java file

Comment: @ShadowDroid Please recheck my post.

Comment: initialize helper and myhelper class first